# Работа с прерываниями

Tags: pascal, прерывания

Есть резидентная программа на паскале. При нажатии клавиши Enter в командной строке, когда программа работает, происходит некоторое событие (например, вывод на экран) путём обработки прерывания клавиатуры. Когда же выполняется какая-либо команда (dir, cls, mem) и нажимается Enter событие из обработчика клавиатуры резидентной программы не выполняется.

Прошу прощения! Мой первый вопрос :)
Вот минимальный пример:

```
{$M, $1000, 0,0}
program lab5;

uses
  crt, dos;

type video = array [1..25,1..80] of
 record
 symbol : char;
 attr : byte;
 end;

var
  memory : video absolute $B800:$0000;
  OldKey : procedure;

{$F+}
procedure Key; Interrupt;
begin

if (Port[$60] = 156) then {Скан-код клавиши Enter}
 begin
 memory[WhereY,WhereX].Symbol := '1';
 end;

Inline($9C);
OldKey;

end;
{$F-}

begin
  GetIntVec($9, @OldKey);
  SetIntVec($9, Addr(Key));
  Keep(0);
end.
```

Команда

```
inline($9C)
```

аналогична:

```
asm PUSHF end;
```

Проблема в том, что каскадная обработка прерывания не выполняется при вызове внешней команды из оболочки. Пробовал использовать линию параллельную IRQ 2.

```
GetIntVec($71, @OldKey);
SetIntVec($71, Addr(Key));
```

Самое интересное, что начало работать, но при этом перестало обрабатывать нажатие Enter без команды и работало не стабильно. И в итоге через небольшое время перестало работать. Так и не разобрался в чем проблема.

Comment: Слава российским IT-археологам. Новизна проблемы может соперничать только с экскрементами мамонтов. (Резидентные программы -- это попытка борьбы с однозадачностью dos, и без dos смысла не имеют)

Comment: @alexlz, и что? Написано же - учебное задание. @rozzzario, довольно слов, покажите код.

Comment: Программа есть. А вопрос где?

Comment: Программа где-то там, а здесь её тоже нет, а наизусть обработку IRQ1 тяжеловато вспомнить будет... Плюсую, прикольно было бы вспомнить низкоуровневые штучки, да еще и на трубопаскакале.

Comment: На мой беглый взгляд всё нормально, единственное, что вызывает сомнения - инлайн перед вызовом старой ISR. Еще раз, какая наблюдается проблема? 

Щас DOS поставлю и попробую...

Comment: Насколько я помню 156 - это код отпускания клавиши а не нажатия. Может из-за этого проблемы? Поставте реакцию просто на прерывание а не только при наличие в порте клавиатуры кода отпускания клавиши

Comment: @Чад, вы правы, старший бит обозначает нажатие/отпускание, а скан-код клавиши Enter - 28.

Comment: @Чад, все подобные варианты уже опробованы :) Не знаю, куда ещё копать, вот и ищу свежего взгляда на проблему. Что ж, видимо, остается ждать ответа преподавателя.

Comment: Ещё вспомнил, что там перед keep делали  вызов `SwapVectors`; Не помню точно, что оно делает, много лет прошло :-)

Может эта ссылка поможет понять: [tsrkeep][1]? 


  [1]: http://pascal.sources.ru/tsr/tsrkeep.htm

Answer (score 2):

Прошу прощения, у меня квота комментариев кончилась, поэтому постщу в виде ответа то, что по сути комментарий.

1. Насчет PUSHF я поднял ложную тревогу, инструкция **нужна** иначе портится стек.
2. Если я правильно помню, с "младшими" векторами (по-моему, редирект клавиатуры это не INT 71) идея тупиковая, т.к. ISR не сможет вызвать INT 10 (`WhereX`, `WhereY`)
3. Насчет `SwapVectors` [[@Чад](/users/7390/%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B4)](/users/7390/%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B4) совершенно верно отметил, также, как и перед `Exec` её вызов **обязателен**. Кстати, это сделает TSR реентерабельным.
4. Я так и не смог воспроизвести неправильного поведения резидента в ограниченных условиях MS-DOS 6.22 под VMWare. У меня успешно пишет '1' в экранный буфер и при нажатии и при отпускании <kbd>Enter</kbd>, хотя часто программы его затирают (пример MS-DOS Editor).
5. По поводу ссылок посмотрите [на второй пост](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/df/25534.html) (О дрѣвности всего этого говорит дата поста - 1902 год :)